# jQuery stop form submission if textfield is empty or not a zip

Tags: jquery, validation

I'm very new to using jQuery but I know it would be the best application for what I need.  I built a small form that has a single input textbox that asks for a zip code.  The form works fine, but I want to make sure the field has a value, and that it's a specific format (zip code). If not, I'd like to stop the SUBMIT dead in its tracks and change the textbox class.

```
<form action="url" class="form-inline" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
    <label for="zipcode">Zipcode</label>
    <input type="text" name="zipcode" value="" maxlength="5" placeholder="" class="form-control">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">Search</button>
</form>
```

I don't want to submit the form using jQuery, I just want to validate before the form submits to `ACTION`

Comment: based on country zip code changes, which country you want

Comment: Just the United States

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the easiest way to disable a form submission before validation is to add the `disabled` attribute to the button and only remove it after validation has passed. If you go this route, you can use a `keyup` event listener on the input field to check validation and enable the submit button accordingly. As for the validation, a simple regular expression to test against should be fine if you're only interested in American zip codes.

```js
const $zipInput = $('input[name=zipcode]')
const $submit = $('button[type=submit]')

function validate(input) {
  const value = input.currentTarget.value
  const regex = /[0-9]{5}/;
  
  if (!regex.test(value)) {
    $submit.prop('disabled', true)
  } else {
    $submit.prop('disabled', false)
  } 
}

$zipInput.on('keyup', function(input) {
  const value = input.currentTarget.value
  
  if (value.length > 4) {
    validate(input)
  } else {
    $submit.prop('disabled', true)
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="url" class="form-inline" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
    <label for="zipcode">Zipcode</label>
    <input type="text" name="zipcode" value="" maxlength="5" placeholder="" class="form-control">
    <button disabled type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">Search</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi based on country zip code changes, 
If you are using jquery validation plugin,  add this method is help full

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("zipUS", function(value, element) {
    return /(^\d{5}$)|(^\d{5}-\d{4}$)/.test(value);
}, "Please specify a valid US zip code.");


$(".form-inline").validate({
    rules: {
        // rules,
        'zipcode': {
            required: true,
            zipUS: true 
        }
    },
   });
```